# Is this term structure model valid? (Modeling the Zerobonds directly)

Tags: arbitrage, martingale, zero-coupon, term-structure

Let us define the dynamics of the discounted Zerobonds as

$$ \tilde{P}(t,T) = \int \sigma(t,T) dW_t + \tilde{P}(0,T)$$
Lets assume $\sigma(t,T)$ is s.t. $\tilde{P}(t,T) $ is a martingale and positive (and nonzero) $\mathbb{P} \ a.s.$ . Lets define a numeraire as follows:

$$ B(t) = \frac{1}{\tilde{P}(t,t)}  $$
And finally define the dynamics of the actual Zerobonds by

$$P(t,T) = \tilde{P}(t,T) B(t)$$

Now by construction $P(t,t) =1 \forall t$ and  there exists a numeraire (namely $B(t)$) s.t. the discounted Zerobonds are martingales.

I think $B(t)$ is a valid numeraire. It is by assumption strictly positive and I could show in the discrete case that it is an tradable asset (it can be replicated by trading in zerobonds). For the continuous case I have the following starting point

Lets assume the brownian motion is one dimensional. We need a selffinancing trading strategy $\phi$ in Zerobonds s.t.

$$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \phi_{i,t} P(t,t_{i}) = B(t)$$

which is equivalent to

$$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \phi_{i,t} \tilde{P}(t,t_{i}) = 1$$
This is where I am not sure in the continuous case. in the discrete case $\tilde{P}(t,t_{i}) $ results from $\tilde{P}(t-\Delta,t_{i}) + \sigma_{t,T}\varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\Delta)$. Since $\varepsilon$ is equal for all Zerobonds we can find $\phi_{1t}$ and $\phi_{2t}$ s.t. on one hand
$$ \phi_{1t}\sigma_{t,t_1}\varepsilon   + \phi_{2t} \sigma_{t,t_2}\varepsilon=0 $$
(where I assumed that $\sigma_{t,T}$ is predictable)
and on the other hand

$$\phi_{1t}\tilde{P}(t,t_{1}) + \phi_{2t}\tilde{P}(t,t_{2})=1 $$
These equation guarantee that the value of the portfolio matches the value of the numeraire and furthermore that the cost of setting up this portfolio at $t-\Delta $ equals:

$$\phi_{1t}P(t-\Delta,t_{1}) + \phi_{2t}P(t-\Delta,t_{2}) =B(t-\Delta)(\phi_{1t}\tilde{P}(t,t_{1}) + \phi_{2t}\tilde{P}(t,t_{2})) =B(t-\Delta) $$

Thus we have a selffinancing portfolio with initial cost $B(0)$ that replicates the $B(t)$ which makes it a numeraire.

So all in all this implies that this model is arbitrage-free.

Is this reasoning valid? If not where got I wrong? If yes, why haven't I seen this anywhere? Is it not practical to work directly with zerobonds?

Comment: It is trivial that $\tilde{P}(t,T)$ is a *local* martingale. The assumption on $\sigma(t,T)$ that it is a true martingale should not be too restrictive. What bothers me a lot more is that even the simplest $\sigma(t,T)$ I can think of (deterministic and not zero) will ensure that $\tilde{P}(t,T)$ is almost surely as negative as you like.

Comment: How about $ \sigma(t,T)=\tilde{P}(t,T)\sigma $ with $\tilde{P}(0,T)>0$   which is basically the black scholes setting, Thus ensuring positive prices. .

Comment: Exactly. This works. Then you have the good old HJM model in bond price format. In short: your model is valid. See Musiela Rutkowski around p. 303.

Comment: I looked into it but I couldn't find a connection between the approach above and the HJM or shortrate approach. It is clear that in all cases the discounted zerobonds are positive martingale ito processes under the risk neutral measure. Thus exactly of the form above.  But I am not seeing how the numeraire above fits into all this. could you maybe elaborate?

Comment: I don't understand what your numeraire $B(t)=1/\bar{P}(t,t)$ is. This is surely not the price of something, and, afaik a numeraire has to be exactly that. If you take the most well-known numeraire of all, namely, $B(t)=\exp(\int_0^tr_s\,ds)$ (money market account) then $\frac{dP(t,T)}{P(t,T)}=r_t\,dt+\sigma(t,T)\,dW_t$, or equivalently, by Ito's lemma $\frac{d\bar{P}(t,T)}{\bar{P}(t,T)}=\sigma(t,T)\,dW_t\,.$

Comment: Small addition (I think I get it now): With any numeraire (in particular the money market account) $\bar{P}(t,T)=P(t,T)/B(t)$ and $P(t,t)=1\,.$ Thus you have $B(t)=1/\bar{P}(t,t)\,.$ In short: nothing new. Pls study Musiela Rutkowski or any other book that covers HJM.

Comment: It can well be that this is equivalent to some existing framework . What I want to do ist to choose $\sigma(t,T)$ at will and be sure that via above construction I get an arbitrage free term structure model. As you said $B(t)$ has to be tradable. I introduced the proving idea in the initial question. Does it have a flaw?

Comment: The idea is flawless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129495/discussion-between-roman27-and-kurt-g).